# Backbone events not firing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I know other posts have been made regarding this, but so far the answers I've seen have not been helpful, and slightly different from my situation.

```
window.BotView = Backbone.View.extend
  initialize: ->
    _.bindAll @, 'alert', 'render'
    @el # by calling this here, it initializes the jQuery object

  el: $("#submit")

  model: Chatbot

  events:
    "click #submit" : "alert"

  alert: ->
    console.log("alert called")
    alert("event observed")

  render: ->
    alert("Rendered")


jQuery ->
  window.App = new BotView
  console.log App.el
```

All I want is when I click on the submit button with the `id` of `submit` for it to fire the `alert` function. However, I can't even get this to work.

What is going on with the `events` that my simple `click` handler on `#submit` isn't working?

I have double checked that my `el` is properly initialized, but even so, it should not matter because the click handler is not using `el`

Could anyone shed some light on why this simple event is not firing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your events you are saying, in the #submit element, look for an element that gets clicked with the ID of #submit.  Change it to

```
'click' : 'alert'
```

and it should work fine.

The jQuery equivalent of what you have above is this:

```
$('#submit').find('#submit').click(alert);
```

Comment: Actually, a more precise translation is `$('#submit').delegate('#submit', 'click')`... not that it matters in this case, but it's a common point of confusion.